# Qt's foreach expression requires a deep copy?

Tags: c++, qt, foreach

I am having a bit of a problem with Qt's foreach function. I have a class Phrase, which is a subclass of QList. In ~Phrase I delete all of the GlossItem pointers.

In iterating through the GlossItem pointers in Phrase, I would like to use Qt's foreach:

```
    // phrase is a pointer to a Phrase object, 
    // which is a subclassed QList<GlossItem*>
    foreach( GlossItem *glossItem , *phrase )
    {
        // use glossItem
    }
```

For some reason foreach is performing a deep copy on Phrase (I know this because it required me to implement the copy constructor). But if there is a copy of Phrase -- and if I don't want to create a deep copy of each GlossItem -- that means that those pointers will be deleted twice. (Or, deleted once, and then crash.) So I have to use this, which works but is less pretty.

```
    for(int i=0; i<phrase->count(); i++ )
    {
        GlossItem *glossItem = phrase->at(i);
        // use glossItem
    }
```

Is there a way around this or do I just need to live with it?

Comment: In your first example, you use an index variable `i` - where does that fit in?

Comment: Also, I don't see any evidence that `QList` has a virtual destructor, which allows you to inherit from it.

Comment: That's not a good design: containers are meant to be copied, deleting its content in the dtor will break (Use Q_DISABLE_COPY to prevent copies). As Tony says, QList doesn't have virtual dtor, so it's not a good idea to inherit from it. Design hint: never inherit from containers, but make them a member of some wrapper class instead. class Phrase { QList<GlossItem*> list() const; ... Q_DISABLE_COPY(Phrase) };

Comment: That index variable was a copy/paste error, Component 10, which I edited. Thanks for the design input, Frank. I was suspicious of subclassing a QList when I first coded this, but now I have a concrete reason for not doing so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the docs

> Qt automatically takes a copy of the container when it enters a foreach loop.

and

> Since foreach creates a copy of the container, using a non-const reference for the variable does not allow you to modify the original container.

So I think for your specific use case `foreach` isn't suitable otherwise you end up with a fresh copy of the `Phrase` with additional pointers, rather than returning the actual original `Phrase` that you want.

Comment: I was never aware of that - at first glance a horrible way to implement foreach. Why did the trolls make this decision? If the iterator was required to be a const ref, one would have a chance to notice this unexpected behaviour, but the way it is implemented, you wouldn't notice until you iterate over something that connot be copied by the default copy contstructor.

Answer (score 1):

No, if you look at the code expanded from `foreach`: qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/HEAD/src/corelib/global/qglobal.h#line2371
It use const_iterator. Yes, it do copy the container but since all container class in Qt is implicit shared, it is just shallow copy, not deep copy.