# Warning removing dynamically created structs from QList of structs

Tags: c++, qt, struct, dynamic, heap-memory

I am writing q Qt5/C++ program with the following types:

```
struct SSensorScore {
    Types::EScoreComparisons comparisonType;
    ESensorValueTypes comparisonValueType;
    QVariant comparisonValue;
};
typedef QList<SSensorScore> TSensorScoreList;
TSensorScoreList scoreList;
```

I append items to my scoreList list this:

```
SSensorScore *newScore = new Types::SSensorScore;
newScore->comparisonType = comparisonType;
newScore->comparisonValueType = Types::ESensorValueTypeUnknown;
newScore->comparisonValue = QVariant(config_score);
scoreList.append(*newScore);
```

and I remove them like this:

```
foreach (Types::SSensorScore score, scoreList) delete &score;
```

Is there something wrong with doing the above?  When compiling the last line (delete the struct) gives me an error that 'the address of score will never be null'.  So what?  I must be missing the point of the warning...

Perhaps I'm confused about how to create a QList of dynamically created structs.  Do I need to change my QList to a list of pointers?  Do I need to cast my score so that delete knows it's dynamically created?

Comment: You've messed everything up: pointers, variables, etc. Simple answer should be like "use `QSharedPointer` and you will not need to delete manually your pointers.". Do you need to store object or pointers? Decide and do that instead of ...

Comment: That seems to compile without warning.  But doesn't that mean scoreList is a QList of pointers to the struct?  (Which it is not - it is a QList of struct)

Comment: Code can't be `very bad` without any warnings. From what I see here you simply can use objects without pointers here. Why do you need pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  memory leak and undefine behaviour! :

```
scoreList.append(*newScore);
```

this line is going to copy the `*newScore` and then append it to `scoreList`. so you will leak `newScore`.

and this line :

```
foreach (Types::SSensorScore score, scoreList) 
  delete &score;
```

It will delete the the copy of object  so it's undefine behaviour.

and also Qt make a copy of container [before entering foreach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14317503/qts-foreach-expression-requires-a-deep-copy) . so even if you fix the first problem still it won't delete anything!

just change your code to :

```
SSensorScore newScore;
newScore.comparisonType = comparisonType;
newScore.comparisonValueType = Types::ESensorValueTypeUnknown;
newScore.comparisonValue = QVariant(config_score);
scoreList.append(newScore);
```

and you won't have to  delete your list's item using that `foreach`.

Comment: So you're saying that the append function makes a COPY of the object before appending it to the list?  (I didn't notice that in the docs)

Comment: And, how are you recommending I delete my score items then?

Comment: @GenerationDSystems The docs assume you know the C++ semantics. To remove just use the approrpiate remove function, once it is in the list then the list will take care of the deleting the object when needed

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - getting my head around this.  the .clear() method now does what I need, and no worry about leaked memory.